# sorting suffixes by qsort

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, suffix-array

I am trying to sort suffixes of a string by qsort() but not getting the sorted list .

what should i do ?
Here is what i have done :

```
char str[MAXN]="banana", *a[MAXN];

for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
   a[i]=&str[i];  //a[] points to suffixes starting

qsort(a, n, sizeof(char *), compare);
```

this is my compare() function :

```
int compare(const void* p, const void* q)
{
     char *a= (char*)p;
     char *b= (char*)q;

    return strcmp(a,b);
}

a[i] points to i'th suffix of str = "banana"
a[0]: banana    
a[1]: anana    
a[2]: nana    
a[3]: ana
a[4]: na
a[5]: a

after qsort() i want to get :

a[0]: a
a[1]: ana
a[2]: anana
a[3]: banana
a[4]: na
a[5]: nana
```

the problem is that i am getting unsorted list.

Comment: Where's the `n`? Is it `size_t n = strlen(str);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `compare` function receives pointers to items in the array. Since the array items here are pointers to `char`, what it receives is pointers to pointers to `char`:

```
int compare(const void* p, const void* q)
{
     char **a= (char**)p;
     char **b= (char**)q;

    return strcmp(*a,*b);
}
```

Comment: You are passing `n=0`. That means that 0 items are sorted.